# How to get all interfaces that a class implements?

Tags: java, reflection

In my test below, why is [`Aa.class.getClasses()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClasses%28%29) returning `[]` not `[A.class]`? `A` is `public` after all.

```
import org.junit.Test;  
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class GetClassesTest{     

    public interface A {}
    class Aa implements A {}

    @Test
    public void getClassesShouldWork(){
        assertThat( "should fail, but passes", Aa.class.getClasses(), is( new Class[]{} ) );
//      assertThat( "should pass, but fails!", Aa.class.getClasses(), is( new Class[]{ A.class } ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because `getClasses()` returns the classes and interface that a class **defines** not **implements**. What you want is [`Class.getInterfaces()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces%28%29).

```
import org.junit.Test;  
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

public class GetInterfacesTest{     

    public interface A {}
    class Aa implements A {}

    @Test
    public void getInterfacesDoesWork(){
        assertThat( "should pass, and passes", Aa.class.getInterfaces(), is( new Class[]{A.class} ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have nothing against self answers, but isn't this a matter of reading the docs?

Comment: lol. How did you do that? You asked a question and gave the answer yourself within the same second!

Comment: Glass half-full: he had a tough issue that he fixed himself, and wanted to share with the community. Glass half-empty: he tried to boost his reputation points.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I found `getClasses()` and stopped reading further unless I was banging my head against a wall because it _seemed_ like what I needed but failed to appreciate a nuance (specifically `"that are members of the class represented by this Class object."` meant "defined") While I was typing up the question I came across the answer in case it would help other who did the exact same thing I did. I don't think this answer/question is zero value add. I'm also content with my reputation score and don't need more internet points.

Comment: @isnot2bad at the bottom of the submit question form under the `Post Your Question` button there is a checkbox for `"Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style"`.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I don't mind that much (didn't downvote either). I definitely see where you're coming from, but if everyone would post a solution that is basically just looking up the correct method in the API, the site would get flooded with all possibly variants.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Well my excuse is that `member` is rather technical and its tricky here. What's funny is that the people who think I'm trying to farm points just gave me a chance to earn the "Peer Pressure" badge (not that I care, just humorous).

Comment: Nevertheless: +1 for the question. Class#getClasses() is misnamed in my opinion.

Comment: Why would it be misnamed? A class can only extend from 1 superclass so saying it would return classes it extends would make no sense. And this would automatically exclude interfaces it implements. `getClasses()` is thus very appropriate for classes defined inside the current class. `getInterfaces()` makes a lot more sense to return the interfaces it implements.

Comment: `getInnerClasses()` would have been an even better name, to me I was think `getClass()` gets the class this in directly instance of, so `getClasses()` would return all the classes this is an instance of. It really doesn't parallel `getClass()` despite the similarity in name.